# Prevent crawling of mobile site

Tags: robots.txt, bing, googlebot

I have an issue with bots crawling the mobile site and returning hits on the mobile site for desktop users.

The mobile content is in /mobile/
The regular site will redirect mobile users to the /mobile/ site
Regular desktop browsers are allowed into the /mobile/ site and will see the mobile version (used for easy testing of mobile content from desktop).

Can someone help with a sane robots.txt for this site that would work with Google and Bing. I want both crawlers to index the  hole site, but only the mobile crawler should index the mobile site.

I have found user-agent: GoogleBot-Mobile for google, but is there something like BingBot-Mobile or does it crawl only with bingbot? Also, is msnbot gone?

Is this ok?

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot,bingbot
Disallow: /mobile/
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile,bingbot-mobile
Disallow: /
Allow: /mobile/
```

I guess it would be better if desktop users got redirected away from the /mobile/ site to the regular content, but it's a bit outside scope of question.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should handle this issue differently. You want google to understand it's an alternate page version that is for different screen sizes. He will make sure a desktop user will be directed to the right place (as well as mobile users).

I would recommend the following:

In all /mobile/ pages use:

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="/non-mobile-url"/>
```

And in the non mobile url put this

```
  <link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" href="/mobile/..." />
```

Comment: This is a nice solution! Do you know if this index behavior is documented on the Google side?

Answer (score 2):

Each bot requires its own line.

### Your robots.txt should look like this

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /mobile/
Allow: /

User-agent: bingbot
Disallow: /mobile/
Allow: /

User-agent: Googlebot-Mobile
Disallow: /
Allow: /mobile/

User-agent: bingbot-mobile
Disallow: /
Allow: /mobile/
```

### Additional its always best to use Noindex and Robots.txt

You should consider using both robots and noindex... Simply use the following metas.

**On the mobile site and not the normal site**

```
<meta name="Googlebot" content="nofollow, follow">
<meta name="bingbot" content="noindex, follow">
```

**On all the normal pages and not the mobile site use:**

```
<meta name="Googlebot-Mobile" content="nofollow, follow">
<meta name="bingbot-mobile" content="noindex, follow">
```